# Load SWF Content Js on Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an JS function in my page and when the page is load, my sfw content is loading normaly, I have added the ButtonClienClick to call my JS Function to show the div that contain my SWF content, but when the button click is fired my swf do not load. Any sugestion to load this content on button click?

```
    function ShowDialogLoading()
    {
        $('#example').flash(
            { 
                src: 'Img/banner_aguarde.swf',
                width: 902,
                height: 320
            }
        );   
        $("#example").dialog({
            create: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-widget-header").hide();
                $(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding","0px");
            },
            modal: true,
            title: 'Pagamento Pré-Pago',
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false, 
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto' 
        });                      
    } 


 <asp:Button ID="btnProximoPasso" CssClass="form-button" OnClientClick="ShowDialogLoading()" runat="server" Text="Próximo Passo"
                            OnClick="btnProximoPasso_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

// use the jQuery alternative for flashembed.domReady
$(function() {

    // bind an onClick event for this second Flash container
    $("#flash2").click(function() {

        // same as in previous example
        $(this).flashembed("/swf/flash10.swf");
    });
});
</script>
<asp:Button ID="flash2" runat="server" Text="Load"/>
</body>
<html>
```